# Can I send output from for loop into R presentation?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have not really used R MD before so I'm not really sure what to do here.

I have a long for loop that runs through all my data and generates plots and runs the stats. Currently, it just saves the plots as .png and writes the results for each to excel. That means with each iteration the plot `p1` is overwritten, as is `anovaresults`. This fine for saving the results. But I would like to stick them all in an R presentation file.

Is there a line I can add at the end of the loop that will send the results of each iteration to an R presentation before it is overwritten?

Cheers

Comment: Just `plot(p1)` inside the loop should do it. — But without code to look at it’s hard to tell.

Comment: won't that get overwritten by each subsequent p1 plot?

Comment: Just try it! — Plots in RMarkdown don’t overwrite each other, they get appended.